# Event received only by one bean? (despite having several ones)

Tags: java, spring

I am confused with this. I created three instances of beans which should listen to events, but only one of them catches the event. Why? Please see code and output below. PS. new to spring.

Event handler class

```
package customevents.di;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;

public class CustomEventHandler implements ApplicationListener<CustomEvent> {

    private static int ID = 0;

    public CustomEventHandler() {
        ID++;
        System.out.println("Constructor called CustomEventHandler " + ID);

    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.toString() + " " + ID); // Prints My Custom event and ID
    }

}
```

Publisher

```
package customevents.di;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisherAware;

public class CustomEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {

        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void publish() {
        CustomEvent ce = new CustomEvent(this);
        publisher.publishEvent(ce);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      CustomEventPublisher cvp = 
      (CustomEventPublisher) context.getBean("customEventPublisher");

      // Scope of these beans is prototype
      CustomEventHandler ce =  (CustomEventHandler) context.getBean("customEventHandler");
      CustomEventHandler ce1 =  (CustomEventHandler) context.getBean("customEventHandler");
      CustomEventHandler ce2 =  (CustomEventHandler) context.getBean("customEventHandler");

      cvp.publish();

   }
```

Output

```
Constructor called CustomEventHandler 1
Constructor called CustomEventHandler 2
Constructor called CustomEventHandler 3
Constructor called CustomEventHandler 4
My Custom Event 4
```

Why only one bean received the event?

PS. Adding beans file as requested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="customEventHandler" class="customevents.di.CustomEventHandler" scope="prototype">      
   </bean>

   <bean id="customEventPublisher" class="customevents.di.CustomEventPublisher">      
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you add the `Beans.xml` content ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Sure, please find it.

Comment: You can't know for sure if it's the fourth bean that got the event. Your `ID` is static, so any of the beans will print "My Custom Event 4". The problem seems to be that only one bean receives the event (the message is printed only once). Am I right ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Yeah fourth was meant here not in a strict sense, but yeah, only one of them gets it

Comment: Apparently, this cannot work for prototype beans. The internal event dispatching code will find the listener beans as *bean IDs*, and all your beans share the same ID. I'm still trying to find out whether this is documented somewhere...

Comment: @CostiCiudatu ah I see, if you find that documented, feel free to post answer, I will accept it, otherwise you can still post an possible explanation, I will accept (if there are no other answers) it maybe it will be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE1:

[Staphanee Nicoll](https://disqus.com/by/snicoll/) has described in [spring blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2) as below:

> The actual processing of the event will respect the semantics you set
>   on your bean. So if you set prototype we are going to create a new
>   instance of the bean for you prior to call the method on it. And we're
>   going to do that for every event. If you expect all your *existing*
>   prototype instances to be called for a particular event, that's not
>   going to happen (we never did multicast an event and that
>   infrastructure is not meant to do that).

---

You have missed to add `cvp.publish()` for calling every custom event handler.

Another issue `static` section is already described by [costi-ciudatu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262683/costi-ciudatu)

Hope it will work.

For learning more, you can go through this tutorial: [Custom events in spring](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/custom_events_in_spring.htm)

### Github Resource Link:

[Spring app event demo](https://github.com/omanand/spring-app-event-demo)

Comment: Like I said your examples don't seem to solve the issue, please feel free to recreate my scenario from my question, and see if you get different output. With above code constructor is being called 6 times now. I suspect publish call is creating new instance each time.

Comment: Yes you are right. It has some limitation for previous spring version.

Comment: I will check that, I guess I am using 4.2.6 version libs.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Please have a look on UPDATED1 portion.

Comment: Your quote in the beginning seems correct, I think you can remove other part of the answer.

Comment: Walker: I meant I think your quote from Nicoll is enough - IMO it explains the issue, other part I tried and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I have updated the answer. Please check again and let me know if anything need to modify.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing seems to be a limitation of spring, at least in some older versions, and should have been fixed. Some users report it is still broken, so you might need to file a ticket if you are using a version of spring that should work.

I have found the following tickets:

- [SPR-722](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-722)
- [SPR-5248](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5248)

Answer (score 1):

Spring will register the listener when the context starts. So it will create a new instance of your bean when the event is fired.

But you can also register your listener instances at runtime (**context.addApplicationListener(ce);**), use something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

    CustomEventPublisher cvp = (CustomEventPublisher) context.getBean("customEventPublisher");

    // Scope of these beans is prototype
    CustomEventHandler ce = (CustomEventHandler) context.getBean("customEventHandler");
    context.addApplicationListener(ce);
    CustomEventHandler ce1 = (CustomEventHandler) context.getBean("customEventHandler");
    context.addApplicationListener(ce1);
    CustomEventHandler ce2 = (CustomEventHandler) context.getBean("customEventHandler");
    context.addApplicationListener(ce2);

    cvp.publish();

}
```

Comment: this seems to work. feel free to add bit explanation as to why.

Comment: I haven't find information about how the context register the event listeners. But you can see how it works, you can add an id generation on the event listener and print it when the event is publish. It should be a different id every time you publish an event (this apply only for beans registered automatically). The information i've found is (Standard and Custom Events) http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html.

Answer (score 0):

Key thing here is that the `ApplicationListener` instances are registered during startup of the `ApplicationContext` (Take a look at `ApplicationEventMulticaster` and its implementation).

In your case, this means the registered `ApplicationListener` instance is actually the prototype scoped bean with id `customEventHandler` defined in your `Beans.xml` and it's the one that handles the event you published.

What you should do is obtain the `ApplicationEventMulticaster` from the application context and use it to register your beans created in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that only the fourth bean gets notified. But that last bean is one that you didn't create yourself (as you only called `getBean` three times).

If you remove the `cvp.publish()` line from your code, you'll see that only three beans get created.

The 4th one is actually created during the event dispatching. The behavior is explained by the code in [AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.html#getApplicationListeners-org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent-org.springframework.core.ResolvableType-). It simply stores the bean names that implement `ApplicationListener` and then it performs a `BeanFactory.getBean()` when it needs to notify listeners.

Here's the relevant code (in method `getApplicationListeners()`, version 4.0.3.RELEASE):

```
for (String listenerBeanName : listenerBeans) {
    try {
        Class<?> listenerType = beanFactory.getType(listenerBeanName);
        if (listenerType == null || supportsEvent(listenerType, event)) {
            ApplicationListener<?> listener =
                    beanFactory.getBean(listenerBeanName, ApplicationListener.class);
            if (!allListeners.contains(listener) && supportsEvent(listener, eventType, sourceType)) {
                retriever.applicationListenerBeans.add(listenerBeanName);
                            allListeners.add(listener);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
                    // Singleton listener instance (without backing bean definition) disappeared -
                    // probably in the middle of the destruction phase
    }
}
```

It makes sense, if you think that a `prototype` bean is after all just a "prototype" / "template". The container doesn't hold a reference for the actual instances that get created. It will always invoke `getBean()` when it needs one and this will result in a new instance.

Comment: I also expressed suspicion on 4th bean after an answer here. So using approach I have, seems I can't notify existing beans?

Comment: Not prototypes; or, more accurately, not prototype instances. There's only one "bean" from the container perspective -- and that gets created every time. This is definitely not what you want, so you should probably make use of an event dispatching system other than spring.